# Why does help(lambda) gives SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, lambda

I was trying to see what Python would say about lambda.

```
print(help(lambda))
```

Then I get:

```
print(help(lambda))
                 ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Why?

Comment: The same happens for type(lambda) and help(def).

Comment: quote it, `help('lambda')`

Comment: From the dos: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help `If the argument is a string, then the string is looked up as the name of a module, function, class, method, keyword, or documentation topic, and a help page is printed on the console.`, so you need to quote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `help` takes *an object*.

That is, a class, class instance (object), function...

But `lambda` is neither of those things - it's just a keyword that signifies a function definition. Same thing for `def`. Other keywords are e.g. `for`, `in`.

If you need help about lambda, you can't pass it to `help`, you need to search in `help()` like taurus05 said.

Edit: It seems that if you pass a string, help automatically does the search. So `help('lambda')`, `help('def')` and all the others work!

Answer (score 0):

Help function returns the help related to python module, object or method if it is called with the respective argument but without any argument, it will return the help related to currently running programming module.
If you need assistance on what lambda does, and how it works, you can do it this way :

```
>>> help()

Welcome to Python 3.7's help utility!

If this is your first time using Python, you should definitely check out
the tutorial on the Internet at https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/.

Enter the name of any module, keyword, or topic to get help on writing
Python programs and using Python modules.  To quit this help utility and
return to the interpreter, just type "quit".

To get a list of available modules, keywords, symbols, or topics, type
"modules", "keywords", "symbols", or "topics".  Each module also comes
with a one-line summary of what it does; to list the modules whose name
or summary contain a given string such as "spam", type "modules spam".


help> lambda
Lambdas
*******

   lambda_expr        ::= "lambda" [parameter_list] ":" expression
   lambda_expr_nocond ::= "lambda" [parameter_list] ":" expression_nocond

Lambda expressions (sometimes called lambda forms) are used to create
anonymous functions. The expression "lambda parameters: expression"
yields a function object.  The unnamed object behaves like a function
object defined with:

   def <lambda>(parameters):
       return expression

See section Function definitions for the syntax of parameter lists.
Note that functions created with lambda expressions cannot contain
statements or annotations.

Related help topics: FUNCTIONS
```